# How to separate java file from the activities, and call them in each activity?

Tags: java, android, function, android-activity

I'm trying to separate some specific functions from the activities and put them under the source directory so that I can call them in each activity. For now, in activity1,2,3, I write down "helloTable(int index) in each activity, meaning when I change a bit in helloTable in activity1, I also have to change the remaining helloTable(s) in activity2 and 3 to make them same as. If I were to make global helloTable for all possible activities, then I wouldn't have had to repeat all procedures again and again. Here, index is just integer variable, INDEX is integer parameter and output type of helloTable is also an integer.

For now, abstract program goes like this for each activity.

```
<Activity1.java>
... 
int Level = helloTable( index );
...
private int helloTable ( int INDEX)
{
    int output;
    if(INDEX<5)
    { output=0;}
    else
    { output=1;}
    return output;
}
...//activity1 ends.

<Activity2.java>
... 
int Level = helloTable( index );
...
private int helloTable ( int INDEX)
{
    int output;
    if(INDEX<5)
    { output=0;}
    else
    { output=1;}
    return output;
}
...//activity2 ends.

<Activity3.java>
... 
int Level = helloTable( index );
...
private int helloTable ( int INDEX)
{
    int output;
    if(INDEX<5)
    { output=0;}
    else
    { output=1;}
    return output;
}
...//activity3 ends.
```

Please help me and I want to listen to the many expert's opinion :)

Comment: Please create a minimal code example that we can copy and paste. The code should exactly recreate the issue you are asking about. You probably need to start with a single activity and a single class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the method public and call it from your main activity from a static variable.

So to call the method you would write...

```
<AnyOtherClass.java>

    int level = MainActivity.getInstance().helloTable(yourValue);

<AnyOtherClass.java>
```

The code would look something like this...

```
<Activity1.java>
    private static MainActivity mInstance;

    public static MainActivity getInstance() {

        return mInstance;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mInstance = this;
   }

   public int helloTable ( int INDEX ) {
        int output;

        if(INDEX<5)
        { output=0; }
        else
        { output=1; }

        return output;
    }
<Activity1.java>
```

Comment: Thanks! I also tried this method :)!

Comment: No problem, glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could move your helloTable to a separate class and make it public.

For example:

```
public class HelloTable
{
    public int helloTable ( int index )
    {
        int output;
        if( index < 5 )
        {
            output = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            output = 1;
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

Use this by instantiating this class in your activities.

At the top:

```
private HelloTable mHelloTable;
```

In your onCreate:

```
mHelloTable = new HelloTable();
```

To use it:

```
int level = mHelloTable.helloTable( index );
```

If you want to add more methods, then you can add them in this class.

Note: Storing values would only apply to that instance and you would have to do something different like create a singleton class to have one instance.

Comment: Thanks! It works clearly, and I don't no longer need to change several times of same functions!!! :)